# Expo App: The action 'TOGGLE_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I was trying to show a drawer from MealsNavigator navigation.

So far I imported the ff essentials:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Then on my code I tried to call the drawer toggle via `navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());`:

```
const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
          <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                // I CALLED IT HERE ----->>>>>
                                onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
                                }}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
          })}
        />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Here's my drawer nav code:

```
const mainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsFavTabNavigator} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };
```

But in the end this returns an error `The action 'TOGGLE_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator'`

And there is no drawer showed up when I click on the burger menu button on the left side.

What am I missing here?

Note: I am using React Navigation Version 5

UPDATE: Pasting my complete code here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';

import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

import FiltersScreen from '../screens/FiltersScreen';

import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { CATEGORIES, MEALS } from '../data/dummy-data';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
          <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    title: 'Meals Categories',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
                                }}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
          })}
        />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
        : createBottomTabNavigator();

const getNavigationOptions = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        // Props for the ios navigator
        return {
            labeled: false,
            initialRouteName: 'Meals',
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            },
        };
    }
    // Props for android
    return {
        initialRouteName: 'Favorites',
        activeColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveColor: 'black',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor },
        shifting: true
    };
};

const MealsTabNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator {...getNavigationOptions()} >
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Meals"
                    component={MealsNavigator}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesNav}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator();

const FavoritesNav = () => {
    return (
        <FavoritesStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}>
            <FavoritesStack.Screen
                name="Favorites"
                component={FavoritesScreen}
            />
            <FavoritesStack.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const mealId = route.params.mealId;
                    const selectedMeal = MEALS.find((meal) => meal.id === mealId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedMeal.title,
                    };
                }}
            />
        </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
    );
};



const FilterNav = createStackNavigator();

const FiltersNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <FilterNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <FilterNav.Screen
                name="Filters"
                component={FiltersScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Filters'
                }}

            />
        </FilterNav.Navigator>
    );
};


const mainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <mainNavigator.Navigator>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsFavTabNavigator} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </mainNavigator.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };
  
export default MealsTabNav;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a drawer navigator inside the Navigation container.

You have only put the screens.

```
const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <mainNavigator.Navigator>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsFavTabNavigator} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </mainNavigator.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };
```

Comment: After adding that it returns an error `TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function (in navigation.toggleDrawer(); 'navigation.toggleDrawer is undefined()`

Comment: remove the <NavigationContainer> in the MealsTabNav, you should have only one navigation container for the app

Comment: Genius! So I removed that and then exported the `MainNavigatorDrawer` as the main and worked like a charm.

Comment: As you had two containers the internal one was receiving the toggle method and throwing errors :)

Comment: Thank you so much you are a gem to me.

Answer (score 0):

What `Guruparan Giritharan` said about nesting your screens inside a navigator

```
const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <mainNavigator.Navigator>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsNavigator} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </mainNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

To add to that answer I still got an error using dispatch, so instead of dispatch call `toggleDrawer` directly from the navigation prop:

```
onPress={() => {
  navigation.toggleDrawer();
}}
```

**Update**

You are passing

```
const MealsFavTabNavigator =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
```

as a screen. You should pass `MealsTabNav`:

```
const MainNavigatorDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <mainNavigator.Navigator>
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="MealsFav" component={MealsTabNav} />
        <mainNavigator.Screen name="Filters" component={FiltersNavigator} />
      </mainNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

And remove the `NavigationContainer` from `MealsTabNav`.

Comment: After adding that it returns an error `TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function (in navigation.toggleDrawer(); 'navigation.toggleDrawer is undefined()`

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix a problem I saw in your full code, but I can't reproduce that error. Might be handy to create a snack.

Comment: Where should I pass the MealsTabNav? Sorry I'm a bit loss? Can you point it out on your answer where exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I removed the <NavigationContainer> as stated by  Guruparan Giritharan and then exported that as the main import and it works like a charm. I appreciate your help mate!