# The action 'Navigation/TOGGLE_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native

I saw [Expo App: The action 'TOGGLE_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169267/expo-app-the-action-toggle-drawer-was-not-handled-by-any-navigator) and this is a different issue I think.

I have a React Native app for ios and I am working on a NavBar that opens a react navigation menu with a button.

I am using navigation without the navigation prop to achieve this (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/).

When I click my button i get the error: ERROR  The action 'Navigation/TOGGLE_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator.

Here is my code

App.js

```
import {StatusBar, LogBox} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import {NavigationContainer, DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import {ApplicationProvider, IconRegistry} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import {EvaIconsPack} from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Layout from './components/shared/layout';
import {UserProvider} from './config/user-context';

import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import '@react-native-firebase/app';

import Profile from './screens/profile.tsx';
import {navigationRef} from './RootNavigation';


LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Close drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Toggle drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        {/* <Drawer.Scree name="Layout" component={Layout} /> */}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
      <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{...eva}}>
        <UserProvider>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <StatusBar />
            <Layout>
              {/* <StackNavigator />  */}
              <MyDrawer />
            </Layout>
            <Toast ref={ref => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </UserProvider>
      </ApplicationProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

RootNavigation.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {DrawerActions} from 'react-navigation-drawer';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function openDrawer(...args) {
  navigationRef.current?.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
}

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

layout.tsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {
  TopNavigation,
  TopNavigationAction,
  Icon,
  Text,
  IconRegistry,
  Button,
  MenuItem,
  OverflowMenu,
  Select,
  SelectItem,
  IndexPath,
  View,
  Card,
  Modal,
} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import {EvaIconsPack} from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {fab} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import {faBars, faTimes, faUserCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {NavigationContainer, DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import Profile from '../../screens/profile.tsx';


import * as RootNavigation from '../../RootNavigation.js';

library.add(fab, faBars, faTimes, faUserCircle);

const Title = () => <Text category="h1">Astra</Text>;

const Account = () => (
  <Button appearance="ghost">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user-circle" />
  </Button>
);

//This is button that I use to open the Drawer and it gives the error when I click it. 
const OpenMenu = ({navigation}) => (
  <Button onPress={() => RootNavigation.openDrawer()} appearance="ghost">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="bars" />
  </Button>
);

const Layout: React.FC<{children: any}> = ({children}) => {
  const [marg, setMarg] = useState('0%');
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: marg, position: 'relative'}}>
      <TopNavigation
        alignment="center"
        accessoryLeft={OpenMenu}
        accessoryRight={Account}
        title={Title}
      />
      {children}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Thanks